# Torsionness of the kernel of the pullback map of Picard groups of a normalization map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a (irreducible) projective variety over a number field $k$, $\pi: \tilde X \to X$ be its normalization, and $\pi^{*}: \mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(\tilde X)$ be the corresponding map of Picard groups.

I wish to find some nice conditions on $X$ which guarantees that $\mathrm{ker} (\pi^{*})$ is torsion.

However, as R. van Dobben de Bruyn has pointed out in the comments, this is false even for rational curves with a single node.

The reason I'm concerned with this problem is as follows. According to Serre's book "Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem" , the Weil height associated to a line bundle $L$ on $X$ is bounded *iff* $L$ is torsion in $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$, assuming $X$ is non-singular. Now I wish to remove the non-singular hypothesis by resolution of singularities over characteristic-zero fields. However, for now I can only do this for normal $X$, for which one observe that $f_* \mathcal O_{X^{\prime}} = \mathcal O_X$ as $X$ is normal by assumption, therefore $\mathrm{ker} (f^{*})$ is zero by projective formula. Having this in mind, the problem I'm thinking about now comes to the above form.

Comment: Did you try the case $X$ is a simple normal crossings divisor?

Comment: I think for these $X$ we can show “$\mathrm{h}_L$ is bounded *iff* $L$ is torsion” directly by restricting $L$  to each irreducible components of $X$ and apply the original proposition in Serre’s book. From this process we actually see that we may assume $X$ is irreducible. (I have now added this assumption to the body of the question.)

Comment: This is false when $X$ is a rational curve with a single node, e.g. $V(y^2z-x^2(x+z)) \subseteq \mathbf P^3_k$. Indeed, $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X) \cong k^\times$ (a single scalar glueing condition at the two branches of the node) whereas $\operatorname{Pic}^0(\tilde X) = 0$.

Comment: Likewise, this is false for a simple normal crossings divisor on a surface if the dual graph is not a tree, for any loop in the dual graph induces a $\mathbf G_m$ in $\mathbf{Pic}^0$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot. So now it seems that torsionness of $\mathrm{ker}(\pi^*)$ may only hold for a very small class of irreducible projective varieties.